# How to make a toolbar be attached to bottom iOS Swift

Tags: swift, uitabbar, uitoolbar

I have a ploblem with tab bar and navigation bar. There's a toolbar I need to display on top of the tabbar, but attached to the very bottom.

For now I'm getting this:

[image]

My code is:

```
  private func showToolBar() {
    tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
    navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(false, animated: true)

    let archiveButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "deactivateIcons"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(archive))
    let flexibleSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: self, action: nil)
    let refreshButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "changeStatusIcons"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(refresh))
    archiveButton.tintColor = Colors.Purple
    refreshButton.tintColor = Colors.Purple

    setToolbarItems([archiveButton, flexibleSpace, refreshButton], animated: true)

    navigationController?.toolbar.setShadowImage(UIImage(), forToolbarPosition: .bottom)

}
```

So the toolbar appears exactly on top of the tabbar. How to solve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a known issue in iOS. Please report it to Apple as bug.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

put that code in the last line of your showToolBar() function

`let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
navigationController?.toolbar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: screenSize.height - tabBarHeight - 50, width: screenSize.width, height: 50)`